# Web Application on Computer Data with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I want to make a computer storage (online) Web Application with PHP/MySQL... I mean where we can keep all the data of computer and all its configuration, up-gradation, problem occured, solved problems and alerts for warranty expires..

Can any one give me the example link where i can gain some idea (The example can be on any platform). I just want to go thru its work-ability..
I gone thru google, but nothing worth..

Comment: You may not have luck jumping right in to a project like this before spending significant time in "student" mode. I'd start at the library instead of on Google. Start with a PHP "hello, world!", and then move to MySQL-backed site which does simple storage/display of some records, and only then start thinking about trending your learning toward the specific area of interest... Good luck!

Comment: I had created sites with php/mysql.. i just wanted to see the work-ability of app.. anyways thanks for ur comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This company does something like that in their software.  It is called asset management.  It appears to be done using PHP and Ajax as far as I can tell.  I suggest researching Ajax for more info as you will need real-time tracking, i would think. http://www.dapperdesk.com/hd/logina.php